# scale Image in an UIButton to AspectFit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uikit

I want to add an image to a UIButton, and also want to scale my image to fit with the UIButton (make image smaller). Please show me how to do it.

This is what I have tried, but it does't work:

- Adding image to button and using `setContentMode`:

```
[self.itemImageButton setImage:stretchImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.itemImageButton setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

- Making a "stretch image":

```
UIImage *stretchImage = [updatedItem.thumbnail stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
```

Comment: I think this has been changed to be the default behavior in firmware 4.0 and up.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28205566/481207 for the solution.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you really want to scale an image, do it, but you should resize it before using it. Resizing it at run time will just lose CPU cycles.

This is the category I'm using to scale an image :

UIImage+Extra.h

```
@interface UIImage (Extras)
- (UIImage *)imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:(CGSize)targetSize;
@end;
```

UIImage+Extra.m

```
@implementation UIImage (Extras)

- (UIImage *)imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:(CGSize)targetSize {

UIImage *sourceImage = self;
UIImage *newImage = nil;

CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
CGFloat height = imageSize.height;

CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;

CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;

CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize)) {

        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor < heightFactor) 
                scaleFactor = widthFactor;
        else
                scaleFactor = heightFactor;

        scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        // center the image

        if (widthFactor < heightFactor) {
                thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5; 
        } else if (widthFactor > heightFactor) {
                thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
        }
}


// this is actually the interesting part:

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetSize, NO, 0);

CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

[sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

if(newImage == nil) NSLog(@"could not scale image");


return newImage ;
}

@end
```

You can use it to the size you want. Like :

```
[self.itemImageButton setImage:[stretchImage imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:CGSizeMake(20,20)]];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Gcamp. I did have an method for resizing by ratio. But I still try to find a way to tell UIButton do it for me.
My image is load from Internet so I can't resize it at compile time.
BTW, thank you very much for your response.

Comment: Because the image is placed into a CALayer, rendered, and cached by Quartz, performance should not be any worse if you place it in there at full size. Either way, you're resizing ~1 time. gcamp's answer is much more important if you're constantly resizing the button or doing other things that would trigger Quartz to redraw the image layer.

Comment: it seems like image quality is reduced. i am testing on iphone 6 plus. Is it true? I also have 3x image.

Comment: Yes it will, this code is pretty old. It was `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`. Just fixed it.

Comment: yeah but in many cases it doesn't matter if you loose a few cycles, so no point in filling up the ram

Answer (score 210):

I had the same problem.  Just set the ContentMode of the ImageView that is inside the UIButton.

```
[[self.itemImageButton imageView] setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[self.itemImageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:stretchImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Make sure you're setting the **imageView**. I also failed to notice, for a bit, that I was still using the backgroundImageView and it wasn't working for that.

Comment: It seems this method has some problems when the button state is 'highlighted'. The image will back to the fill mode. Any idea?

Comment: It is not working to me. However, I make it work by using [self.itemImageButton setbackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:stretchImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: This worked for me. I set the content mode as above. However, you also need to set the same image of the highlighted state in order to avoid the image going back to "fill mode". For example, [imageButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

Comment: @Dave from Apple doc about imageView **The button’s image view. (read-only)** that's why it does not work

Comment: You can do this in Interface Builder with key path `imageView.contentMode`, type `Number`, and value `1`

Comment: apple help for how to do "bendytree" comment process in Interface Builder - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/Chapters/AddUserDefinedRuntimeAttributes.html

Answer (score 126):

None of the answers here really worked for me, I solved the problem with the following code:

```
button.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
```

You can do this in the Interface Builder as well.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't give you *aspect fit* behavior as asked by the OP.

Comment: @OrtwinGentz you can select the mode and set `Aspect fit` instead of `scale to fill`.

Comment: @Daniel in Xcode 14.1 the `Aspect fit` option acts just like `Scale to fill`, so this doesn't work.

Answer (score 66):

The easiest way to programmatically set a UIButton imageView in **aspect fit** mode :

**Swift**

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
button.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

**Objective-C**

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

---

Note:
You can change .scaleAspectFit (UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit) to .scaleAspectFill (UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill) to set an **aspect fill** mode

Comment: This is the only solution I've found that works. The key is the content*Alignment calls. It also works inside UIStackViews. Thank you!

Answer (score 22):

I had problems with the image not resizing proportionately so the way I fixed it was using edge insets.

```
fooButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 15, 10, 15);
```

Comment: working pretty well, thanks

Answer (score 18):

This can now be done through IB's UIButton properties.  The key is to set your image as a the background, otherwise it won't work.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Expanding on Dave's answer, you can set the `contentMode` of the button's `imageView` all in IB, without any code, using Runtime Attributes:

[image]

- `1` means `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`,
- `2` would mean
  `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`.

Answer (score 13):

1 - clear Button default text (important)

2 - set alignment like image

3 - set content mode like image

[image]

Comment: Nice answer bro..helped me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If you simply want to reduce your button image:

```
yourButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
yourButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

Comment: That should be yourButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Comment: Didn't try with .imageView. It is working without pretty well.

Answer (score 6):

I have a method that does it for me. 
The method takes `UIButton` and makes the image aspect fit.

```
-(void)makeImageAspectFitForButton:(UIButton*)button{
    button.imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment=UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
    button.contentVerticalAlignment=UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

in xCode 13.4.1, configure `Style` to `Default` and `State Config` to `Default`

[image]

Comment: Do this, before setting. 
Control Alignment -  Fill.
Content mode to - Aspect Fit

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5.0

```
 myButton2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
 myButton2.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
 myButton2.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
```

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest solution is to use *Auto Layout*. I lowered *Content Compression Resistance Priority* of my `UIButton` and set the image (not *Background Image*) via *Interface Builder*. After that I added a couple of constraints that define size of my button (quite complex in my case) and it worked like a charm.

Comment: This worked for me -- but only if I selected to use the "Background Image", not the actual image. Whatever works! This was driving me NUTS.

Comment: Under Xcode 6.2 this worked for me but like @AndrewHeinlein said, used `Background Image`

Answer (score 3):

make sure that you have set the image to Image property, but not to the Background

Answer (score 2):

Background image can actually be set to scale aspect fill pretty easily. Just need to do something like this in a subclass of UIButton:

```
- (CGRect)backgroundRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    // you'll need the original size of the image, you 
    // can save it from setBackgroundImage:forControlState
    return CGRectFitToFillRect(__original_image_frame_size__, bounds);
}

// Utility function, can be saved elsewhere
CGRect CGRectFitToFillRect( CGRect inRect, CGRect maxRect )
{
    CGFloat origRes = inRect.size.width / inRect.size.height;
    CGFloat newRes = maxRect.size.width / maxRect.size.height;

    CGRect retRect = maxRect;

    if (newRes < origRes)
    {
        retRect.size.width = inRect.size.width * maxRect.size.height / inRect.size.height;
        retRect.origin.x = roundf((maxRect.size.width - retRect.size.width) / 2);
    }
    else
    {
        retRect.size.height = inRect.size.height * maxRect.size.width / inRect.size.width;
        retRect.origin.y = roundf((maxRect.size.height - retRect.size.height) / 2);
    }

    return retRect;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this possible without a subclass?

Comment: This answer was specifically for backgroundImage. For the main image you can monkey with the the imageEdgeInsets.

Comment: I know, and I wanted if it's possible to achieve this without a subclass.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot adjust the backgroundImage without subclassing.

Answer (score 1):

For Xamarin.iOS (C#):

```
    myButton.VerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Fill;
    myButton.HorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Fill;
    myButton.ImageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
```

Answer (score -1):

**You just need to set content mode of UIButton imageview for three events. -**

```
[cell.button setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[cell.button setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[cell.imgIcon setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

We have code for three event bcoz while highlighting or selecting if button size is SQUARE and image size is rectangle then it will show square image at the time of highlighting or selecting.

I am sure it will work for you.

Comment: You're not setting a content mode, you're setting the image. And they're not events, they're states. You're making a big mess. This is totally unrelated to the question.