# Swift : How to set image to label that fits as per label size?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, uicollectionviewcell

I've UICollectionViewCell that is generated programmatically. There is **label placed over cell.**

Now, I want to set image to label present on cell but that image should resize according to size of cell.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Below is code used but it didn't worked :

```
 let objImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: "OK")!
 let objCGSize = cell.lblNumber?.frame.size

 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(objCGSize!)
 objImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, (cell.lblNumber?.frame.size.width)!, (cell.lblNumber?.frame.size.height)!))

 let objNewImage : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

 cell.lblNumber!.text = ""
 cell.lblNumber!.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: objNewImage)
```

Any other fix?

I tried using UIButton instead of UILabel as suggested by someone. But here another issues cropped-up like Alignment of text, Image is not set..

[image: Screenshot 2]

```
. . . //Code for UIButton instead of UILabel

cell.btnNumber.setTitle("", forState: .Normal)
    //cell.btnNumber.setImage(UIImage(named: "OK"), forState: .Normal)
 cell.btnNumber.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "OK")
cell.btnNumber.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

 . . .
```

Comment: is this button or label bro

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : Label on top of CollectionViewCell

Comment: why you are not choosed the imageview or a button for this concept,it is very easy to work

Comment: this is my suggesstion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("hobbiesCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HobbiesTagCell
        self.configureCell(cell, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    } 

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        self.configureCell(self.sizingCell!, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        return self.sizingCell!.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    }
 func configureCell(cell: HobbiesTagCell, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let tag = tags[indexPath.row]
        cell.hobbiesTagName.text = yourArrname[indexPath.item]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try setting content mode of the UIImageView after setting its frame? It can be done as follows

```
objImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
```

You can use `ScaleToFill` or `ScaleAspectFill`  depending on your requirement. You can find more information about content modes  [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode)

Answer (score 1):

set your button image view Content mode as `ScaleAspectFit` and at the same time set  your button property `setImage` instead of `setBackgroundImage`?

```
yourbutton.imageView?.contentMode =.ScaleAspectFit
yourbutton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .Fill
yourbutton.contentVerticalAlignment = .Fill
yourbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: stretchImage)!, forState: .Normal)
```

for additional Help see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025319/scale-image-in-an-uibutton-to-aspectfit)

Comment: Question has been edited. Check it. Apart from image one new issue poped up..alignment of text is in right bottom of cell.

Comment: text also button or a labelbro

Comment: @JayprakashDubey - your problem is solved or not bro

Comment: Nope...didn't sovled problem.