# set aspect fit for button backgroundImage

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code:

```
myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "image1"), for: .normal)
```

I'm trying to add a background for the button from the code level. I would like to set the aspect fit to this background.
At the moment, the background image is not displayed properly.

Comment: show some UI or some additional code

Comment: A UIButton's background image does not respond to content mode. The simplest way to fix this is to use a UIImageView behind a clear color UIButton.

Comment: see this once may be it helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025319/scale-image-in-an-uibutton-to-aspectfit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

It will work..for **Button's background Image**

Comment: it's fine.@V_rohit